# Cannot find module '/workspace/index.js' error after repository push attempt to railway.app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just had an error I just fixed, but now I am getting this error saying cannot find module workspace, I have no idea what workspace is.

Here is the full error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
```

I don't know how to fix this issue so I would really appreciate it if someone helped me with this one. If you can't help but had the time to view it, still thank you!

Comment: Are you using Yarn? Does your `package.json` [define workspaces](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/).

Answer (score -1):

1.Do you have  **Node.js** installed on your machine?

2.If you have installed node.js, use <node (name of your main file).js> to run

3.Check for the following in the JSON file:

```json
"scripts": {
   "start": "node index.js"
 },
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. In particular, please make sure to answer the actual question being asked. OP is asking a specific question about a workspace error when deploying their code to https://railway.app/. This answer contains three wild guesses, none of which are relevant.